# how to copy images from windows clipboard to WSL2's clipboard

Tags: windows, clipboard, wsl2

I have WSL2/Ubuntu setup in windows, and have `xclip` installed in WSL2.
I am using windows 10 + wsl2 + [gwsl](https://opticos.github.io/gwsl/)
everything works great, I can share the clipboard between windows and WSL2. However, that only works for text/string, if I copy an image under windows, I cannot get it in WSL2 using `xclip`. e.g., if I run  `xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -o image_file.png` I got `Error: target image/png not available`.

If I run `xclip -t TARGETS -o` to check what is in the clipboard, I got `Error: target TARGETS not available`. but for string copied, I got `TARGETS UTF8_STRING STRING`

How can I get xclip to work with copied images on windows host?

Comment: Assuming this is with WSLg/Windows 11, right?  Probably worth it to list it explicitly in the question if so.  I don't *think* there is a way to do it (at least not "out-of-the-box"), but perhaps there's some hack-around that isn't obvious to me at first glance.

Comment: just updated the question, thanks for the note

Comment: just figured that xclip just does not work for WSL2 for clipped images, the workaround is to save image into a file on windows and read into xclip's clipboard on WSL2